# Fabric plugin won't start in Xcode iOS swift app

Tags: crashlytics, twitter-fabric

I have taken over an iOS swift app for my company and opened it in Xcode. Fabric and Crashlytics are installed by cocoa pods. The Fabric framework is listed under Pods and I have installed and configure Crashlytics in accordance with these instructions and the run script has been added to the project target.

https://fabric.io/kits/ios/crashlytics/install

The API has been entered into into info.plist.

I can build and run the project and simulator opens and shows me the project.

Then I tried to follow the instructions below to distribute the project for testing. The first instruction is "make sure the Fabric plugin is running" but I have no idea how to do that. Next I build the archive successfully with Project -> Archive and an archive manager pops up but not Fabric popup. I have tried restarting my mac and Xcode but to no avail. There is nothing in the menu bar, etc to indicate that Fabric exists beyond the files in the project navigator.

https://docs.fabric.io/apple/beta/beta-walkthrough.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mike from Fabric here and our Beta walkthrough is a little confusing if you're using Cocoapods only, so my apologies there.

If you're using the Cocoapods only version of Fabric, then you can use the /submit command to upload distributions via Beta. Full documentation is [here](https://docs.fabric.io/apple/beta/build-tools.html), but there are two options:

1) Add an Archive Post run script action:

```
"${PODS_ROOT}/Fabric/submit" <API_KEY> <BUILD_SECRET> \
-emails TestEmail@fabric.io,AmazingTester@twitter.com \
-notesPath ~/Notes/ReleaseNotes.txt \
-groupAliases GroupAlias,GroupAlias2 \
-notifications YES
```

To add an Archive Post run script, head to Product -> Scheme -> Edit Scheme. Then expand the Archive option, click on "Post-actions", then click on the + sign in the lower-left corner and "New Run Script Action". You can then add the script :)

[image]

2) Run the submit command after the .IPA has been created:

```
${PODS_ROOT}/Fabric/submit <API_KEY> <BUILD_SECRET> \
-ipaPath /path/to/my.ipa -emails TestEmail@fabric.io,AmazingTester@twitter.com \
-notesPath ~/Notes/ReleaseNotes.txt \
-groupAliases GroupAlias,GroupAlias2 \
-notifications YES
```

Alternatively, you can download Fabric.app from [here and](https://www.fabric.io/downloads/apple) follow the rest of the instructions on the Beta walkthrough.

Comment: Thanks Mike, where would I place the script in option 1?

Comment: Updated my answer to include this info :)